# Is it possible to drive or emulate a smartcard using Raspberry Pi?

Tags: smart-card, iso7816

I am trying to learn a little more about the smart card's communication protocols (More specifically T0 and T1 protocols). These cards have 5 pin-outs as below (Vpp is not used) and communicate with the off-card world using the asynchronous half duplex I/O pin (Data in the picture).

[image]

The VCC, GDN, CLK and RST are all derived by the reader and the I/O is derived by reader and card in turn.

The minimum frequency of CLK is 1 MHz and the minimum baud rate in I/O is around 3000 bits/s.

The question is that:

Considering the above mentioned baud-rate and frequency, is it possible to use Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins to emulate a card for a reader? or emulate a reader for a real card?

Note: I/O pin in smartcards is a 3-state pin and when an entity is responsible for the driving the pin (the data transmitter), then the other entity (data receiver) puts its own pin nn Hi-Z state and reads the values.

Comment: Possibly not at 1MHz. If you can slow down the clock rate you might get it to work.

Comment: @user253751 so posts like [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9422/can-a-raspberry-pi-be-operated-at-more-than-115200-baud-rate-i-e-230400) that claim it is possible to transfer data at 22M baud-rate are incorrect?

Comment: it depends on what hardware acceleration you can use. A Pi's CPU can certainly transfer bytes from main memory to the UART circuit at 22M baud (about 2.4 megabytes per second) or more. However, if you're not using one of these standard protocols that has a built-in circuit, that means your program is not just transferring bytes, but turning individual pins on and off with correct timing.

Comment: You might be able to use SPI, but then the clock speed would be the same as the IO speed, so I guess SPI is not the protocol you're using.

Comment: Why do you want to use GPIO pins? It would be far better to just apply clock and use the UART like you would normally do. However the smartcard protocol is not entirely identical to standard UART comms and many microcontrollers have UARTs which can be set into smartcard mode for communicating with smartcards. So it might be possible easily but you need to figure out if the RPi has a smartcard compatible UART mode, and if it does, how to go into that mode.

Comment: @Justme Please correct me if I understood wrongly. You say that I generate CLK using a pulse generator or an oscillator to the card and then use RPi UART in smartcard mode to read/write data on this I/O line? If so, then how the card and the RPi can sync with eachother?

Comment: @E... Can you look up how UART communication works? The card just needs a clock to run at correct speed and then the card and MCU communicate via UART almost like any other two devices over UART.